# Formatting numbers that appear in Sql Server Execution Tooltips

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

Is it possible to format the numbers which appear in SQL Server's Execution Plan Tooltips/Properties? For example in the image below it would be nice to have the **Estimated Number of Rows for All Executions** displayed as 40,660,200 instead of 40660200.
[image: EPToolTip]

I assume the answer is 'no', but I've wondered for years...Thanks and sorry for the trivial question

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible in the native SQL Server Management Studio. But I'd highly recommend using [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) to analyze execution plans which also does format the numbers in the tooltips, among other benefits.

E.g:

[image: SentryOne Plan Explorer]

Note I'm in no way affiliated with SentryOne / SolarWinds, I just love this tool.